# Filtering Expressions in Microsoft Report Builder

Tags: expression, reportbuilder3.0

My dataset has multiple variables each with different values. I am already filtering in my Datasets and Charts/Tables. I need to be able to filter again in my expression.

I want only the values from one variable. I need to filter out the other variables so I can focus only on the values from one variable.

Value=(Fields!VALUE.Value) when Fields!VARIABLE.Value = "ABCD"

Obviously the logic above does not work but I am looking for something similar that does work.

Value is an integer
Fields!VALUE.Value is an integer
Fields!VARIABLE.Value is a string
ABCD is the variable name I want to get the value from.

For example.

I have two variables ABCD and EFGH. I only want the value from ABCD but not from EFGH. I need to filter out EFGH.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.